# Parsing string to float currency

Tags: go

I'm unmarshaling a remote call as a string and I would like to save it locally as a float32.

The string is 22.600 and when I parse that:

```
func parseFloat(toParse string) float32 {
    f, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(toParse, 32)
    return float32(f)
}
```

I get `22.600000381469727`. Of course, that is not what I would like. How can I get a ParseFloat to exactly give me 22.600?

Comment: You can't. There are many resources about this on the web, for instance https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html . Do not use floating point for currency.

Comment: Floating point numbers often cannot represent finite decimal numbers. Use integers if you don't want those "artifacts", especially if you're dealing with money.

Comment: use a format of %.3f    But  using actual floats for currency is a bad bad idea

Comment: return float32(math.Round(f * 1000) / 1000)

Comment: Note that using floating point values for currency is usually _very dangerous_, due to the [imprecise nature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/13860) of floating point arethmetic!

Answer (score 1):

```
func parseFloat(toParse string) float32 {
    toParse := "22.600000381469727"
    f, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(toParse, 32)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.3f", float32(f))
    return s
}
```